# Search within previous resultset of elasticsearch?

Tags: php, search, elasticsearch, full-text-search, elastica

I have question about elasticsearch. I am using php elastica library.
If i search with keyword shirt it gave me 5000 records out of 10000. Now when i insert another keyword in search box like blue, it should search in previous result-set and get only shirt with blue, not in elasticsearch index and give me result from previous result set.
Is it possible in elasticsearch elastica library?